# Jquery, codeigniter working with load and replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-load

This is code for generating page:

```
<div id="mali_oglasi">
    <?php foreach ($mgs as $key) : ?>
    <p class="mali_oglas">
        <span class="name"><?php echo $key['name'] ?></span>
        <span class="body"><?php echo $key['body'] ?></span>
        <span class="contact_author"><?php echo $key['contact_author'] ?></span>
        <span class="date_created"><?php echo $key['date_created'] ?></span>
        <span class="date_expires"><?php echo $key['date_expires'] ?></span>
        <span class="email"><?php echo $key['email'] ?></span>
    <?php foreach ($lokacija as $lok) : ?>
    <?php if($lok['id_location'] == $key['location_id']) : ?>
        <span class="lokacija" id="<?php echo $lok['id_location'] ?>"><?php echo $lok['name'] ?></span>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($kategorija as $kat) : ?>
    <?php if($kat['id_category'] == $key['category_id']) : ?>
        <span class="kategorija" id="<?php echo $kat['id_category'] ?>"><?php echo $kat['name'] ?></span>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <a class="obrisi" id="<?php echo $key['id_global_info'] ?>">Obrisi</a>
    <a class="izmeni" id="<?php echo $key['id_global_info'] ?>">Izmeni</a>
</p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

which will give this result:

```
<div id="mali_oglasi">
        <p class="mali_oglas">

        <span class="name">fbsd</span>
        <span class="body">sdhdsf</span>
        <span class="contact_author">mirko</span>
        <span class="date_created">2012-03-15 11:24:19</span>
        <span class="date_expires">2012-04-14 11:24:19</span>
        <span class="email">a@a.com</span>

                <span class="lokacija" id="1">Pirot</span>

                <span class="kategorija" id="1">Auto i Moto</span>
                                                                                                                                                                                                            <a class="obrisi" id="19">Obrisi</a>
    <a class="izmeni" id="19">Izmeni</a>
</p>
        <p class="mali_oglas">
        <span class="name">dsh</span>

        <span class="body">dshg</span>
        <span class="contact_author">mirko</span>
        <span class="date_created">2012-03-15 11:17:52</span>
        <span class="date_expires">2012-04-14 11:17:52</span>
        <span class="email">a@a.com</span>
                <span class="lokacija" id="1">Pirot</span>


                <span class="kategorija" id="1">Auto i Moto</span>
                                                                                                                                                                                                            <a class="obrisi" id="18">Obrisi</a>
    <a class="izmeni" id="18">Izmeni</a>
</p>....
</div>
```

and JS for `replaceWith` and `load`:

```
$(parent).on('click', '.izmeni', function() {
    var name = $(this).siblings('.name').text();
    var body = $(this).siblings('.body').text();
    var email = $(this).siblings('.email').text();
    var contact_author = $(this).siblings('.contact_author').text();
    var id_lok = $(this).siblings('.lokacija').attr("id");
    var id_kat = $(this).siblings('.kategorija').attr("id");

    $(this).siblings('.name').replaceWith('<input value="' + name + '" />');
    $(this).siblings('.body').replaceWith('<textarea>' + body + '</textarea>');
    $(this).siblings('.date_created').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.date_expires').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.email').replaceWith('<input value="' + contact_author + '" />');
    $(this).siblings('.lokacija').replaceWith(function(){
        $(this).load("<?php echo base_url() ?>form/location", {'id' : id_lok})
    });
    $(this).siblings('.kategorija').replaceWith(function(){
        $(this).load("<?php echo base_url() ?>form/category", {'id' : id_kat})
    });

});
```

load is calling following page (for `lokacija`):

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($lokacija as $lok) : ?>
    <option 
    <?php if($lok['id_location'] == $id) : ?>
        selected="selected"
    <?php endif ?>>
        <?php echo $lok['name'] ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Everything except lokacija and kategorija is replaced, but in the firebug I am getting positive response (page requested page is loaded without the errors but it is not displayed). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dosent LOAD and REPLACEWITH both replace the content, so you are replacing the replaced the content. So can't you just either add the ID to the load method, or make a normal ajax GET and the use the replacewith function?

Comment: I see the erorr in my way of thinking. I just remove the replaceWith function and it is working now :D

Comment: Cool. I just created an answer, so you can close the topic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dosent LOAD and REPLACEWITH both replace the content, so you are replacing the replaced the content.

So can't you just either add the ID to the load method, or make a normal ajax GET and the use the replacewith function?